# ArgumentNullException. UriString Null Parameter when I use UseStorageDevelopment=true to create a TopicClient in AF C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, servicebus

Im Using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 5.1.3

```
var topic = new TopicClient("UseStorageDevelopment=true", anyObject)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are trying to use Storage Emulator for Service Bus.

Storage Emulator works with Azure Storage services (Blobs, Queues and Tables) and Storage Queue is different than Service Bus Queue.

You would need to use a real Service Bus Namespace (there's no emulator support for Service Bus) and use its connection string in your code. Your connection string would look something like `Endpoint=sb://foo.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxx==`